# Retrieve PCF Oauth token and use it to trigger API in PCF Tasks

Tags: oauth, scheduled-tasks, pcf

I am trying to retrieve cf oauth token and use it to trigger another API via PCF Tasks scheduler . I am able to trigger API with no authentication , But when I try to parameterize oauth token I am getting an error that '''[ERR] bash: cf: command not found'''

Command :
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: $(cf oauth-token)" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://somehost.com .

Please suggest